# How to use CreateProcessAsUser in Session 0 to pass SYSTEM account privileges

Tags: c++, winapi

I have made a service program, I hope to use `createProcessAsUser ()` Create a child process in Session 1, the child process also has `system`. what should I do?

Comment: Just [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) instead - _"...Creates a new process and its primary thread. __The new process runs in the security context of the calling process__...."_

Comment: Note that calling `CreateProcess()` in session 0 will run the new process in session 0, whereas `CreateProcessAsUser()` runs the new process in the session of the specified user token. You can't use `CreateProcess()` to target a specific session. But you can use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to target the `SYSTEM` user in a specific session by using `SetTokenInformation(TokenSessionId)`, IIRC